# GRUBのインストール時に発生したエラーの解決法

Tags: ubuntu, grub

使用しているOSはUbuntu18.04.1日本語Remixです。

現在MBRでインストールしてしまった起動ディスクをGPTに変換して
UEFIで起動しようとしています。

これまでにやったことはUEFIでUSBブートした状態で
・sgdisk -gでMBRからGPTに変換
・GPartedで現在のパーティションをリサイズし、頭に空き領域を作る
・fdiskで新たにパーティションを作り、タイプをEFI　システムにして順序を並び替える
・GPartedでファイルシステムをFAT32に、ラベルにboot, espをつける
とここまで来て後はGRUBを入れればUEFIから見えて起動できるかと思っていたのですが
インストールができません。

https://qiita.com/TsutomuNakamura/items/04176b91d791de46142c
http://nort-wmli.blogspot.com/2016/12/uefi-grub-install-grub-update.html
上記の二つを参考にやってみていたのですが

二つのパーティションをそれぞれ/mnt/boot/efi、/mntにマウントし
他のフォルダもマウントした状態でchroot /mntしてインストールをかけたのですが

```
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
rub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: エラー: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

と

```
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: エラー: install device isn't specified.
```

のようになってしまいます。

調べてみてもなかなか解決法がわからずここでつまずいてしまいました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: /dev/sda にパーティションはいくつ有って、それぞれ容量とタイプは何になってますでしょうか？

Comment: /dev/sda1と/dev/sda2があります。1は512MiB、ファイルはFat32、タイプはEFI　システムです。2は446.63GiB、ファイルはext4、タイプはLinux ファイルシステムです。